# IPhone Distribution - Multiple Devices - Not App Store

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, ios-provisioning

I am an individual developer who has written an ipad app for a company.  They have bout 30 devices they want to put it on, so my current plan is to create a provisioning profile that contains all the UDIDS for all those device.  So here are my questions:

1. I surely will miss at least one device and have to either:
   a. Create a new distribution provisioning profile for that device
   or
   b. Add it to the existing provisioning profile, in that case does it void the others
2. Could I submit something to the appstore that is obviously for internal use and password protect it? The company probably isn't willing to do an enterprise account, and I don't want to maintain it by getting them a new provisioning profile every year when they expire.  Any ideas here?

Comment: You have pretty much covered all the options there. Enterprise Account is the "right" way to do it - what's the objection, cost? I could easily see your time wasted eating up that saving if you have to keep adding UDIDs and regenerating provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider Ad Hoc distribution? That would allow you to add the app to a new device without having to make a new provisioning profile.

I haven't done it myself, but this looks useful:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35818-unofficial-ad-hoc-distribution-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I love [TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) for small distributions.  Also, see the [Apple enterprise distribution documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html). It goes over signing and wireless distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Rather if this is going to be used by the company for a longer period of time then I would advice you to go for iOS Developer Enterprise Program.

The main highlighting lines about Enterprise Program is

***"Gain access to resources that will help you develop proprietary, in-house iOS apps that you can distribute to employees or members of your organization."***

So you can distribute the app among your company employees directly without need to submit it on app store. That would surely be a better option.

For more details on iOS Developer Enterprise Program, you can check out this link..

[iOS Developer Enterprise Program](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)